# Group routes for paginated model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, routes

Can I group 3 routes into 1?
I have this in routes.rb:

```
# pagination links for resources
  get '/countries/page/:page', :to => 'countries#index'
  get '/cities/page/:page', :to => 'cities#index'
  get '/spots/page/:page', :to => 'spots#index'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a one liner to DRY your thing up, you can always write ruby code directly in your routes.rb file like so:

`%w(countries cities spots).each{|v| get "/#{v}/page/:page", to: "#{v}#index"  }`